# Android GoogleTv Search Button

Tags: android, google-tv

In my app appears standart quiq Search.activity by pressing on googletv keyboard search button. May I somehow override search button pressing in my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercepting Search Button Press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345369/intercepting-search-button-press)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - unfortunately search on Google TV is Global.  If you want local search in your app, you need to add a search feature that is prominent in your app.

If your apk has it's own Search Provider, you can, of course, (at the users option), join in the Global Search.